# Set up Dynamic dns server

Tags: networking, centos, vps, ddns

I am trying to set up a server at home. The network the server is on will be assigned a dynamic IP address from the ISP. I have looked into services such as DYNdns for a dynamic dns service. However I could also try to build one of my own. I already have a small cloud server that has a static ip address. Does anyone know of good Linux (centos) server applications that could accomplish this and host host my own Dynamic DNS server?

Then I could run a simple app on the Domain Controller of my Home servers to update my public ip address with the dynamic DNS on the VPS.

Thank You

Comment: http://www.dnsknowledge.com/tutorials/centos-tutorials/bind-9/howto-setup-dynamic-dns-ddns/

Comment: It is a lot easier to ask/pay the ISP for a static IP-address. The result will be more reliable.

Comment: I would like a static IP, unfortunately Comcast wont even consider it on residential and its the only ISP available